# how to merge to two table into one complete table and delete duplicates with together criteria

Tags: excel, vba

what i need is merge two table into one and delete the duplicates with criteria.
Table 1 + Table 2 = Table 3

Table1
[image]

Table2
[image]

Table3
[image]

What i need is like table 3.

This criteria normally will in SQL,but i want to do it Excel VBA
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Use Power Query

Comment: Using Power Query, when only it have a complete column of data after to match with other columm it will became more messy.@RicardoDiaz.